# How do you convert a list future to a list to use as a variable not a widget?

Tags: dart, flutter, future

I'm trying to implement the `PaginatedDataTable` class in flutter. A required field in the constructor of this class, is the class `DataTableSource`. Looking at the data table example in the material section of the flutter gallery examples [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/75b24070ddd82336a247373074e325cedfc7d905/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/material/data_table_demo.dart). There is a member variable for the DataTableSource called `List<Dessert> _desserts` where it's values are hard coded. In my implementation, I'm making a http call and returning some json to be decoded.

```
List<Result> parseResults(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = json.decode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

  return parsed.map<Result>((json) => Result.fromJson(json)).toList();
}

Future<List<Result>> fetchResults(http.Client client) async {
  final response = await client.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/j5xau');

  // Use the compute function to run parseResults in a separate isolate
  return compute(parseResults, response.body);
```

In my DataTableSource class I'm not sure how to instantiate the list.

```
`final List<Result> results = fetchResults(http.Client);`
```

doesn't compile because `fetchResults()` returns a future. If I change the return type to a future the `results` does compile but I need my returned json to be of type `List` so I can use methods like `sort` etc..How should I convert the future to a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `DataTableSource` class just remove the `results` variable. Then in your `build` function, you can use a `FutureBuilder` widget like this:

```
FutureBuilder<List<Result>>(
  future: fetchResults(http.Client), 
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Result>> snapshot) {
    switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
      case ConnectionState.none:
        return Text('Press button to start.');
      case ConnectionState.active:
      case ConnectionState.waiting:
        return Text('Awaiting result...');
      case ConnectionState.done:
        if (snapshot.hasError)
          return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
        return Text('Result: ${snapshot.data}');
    }
    return null; // unreachable
  },
)
```

Note that `snapshot.data` is a `List<Result>` now and you can use it in the same way you were using it back when it was a hard coded value.

**Edit:**

If you don't want to use a `FutureBuilder` I would suggest that you have a function that basically modifies the value of the `results` when the http call completes. Here's an example of what I mean:

Make `DessertDataSource` take in a `List<Result>` in its constructor to define the value of `results` like so:

```
class DessertDataSource extends DataTableSource {
  final List<Result> results;
  DessertDataSource(this.results);
  // rest of the class
}
```

In the `_DataTableDemoState`, make  `_dessertsDataSource` no longer final and change its initial value  to `DessertDataSource([])`. Also, add a boolean indicating when the data is loaded already or not.

```
class _DataTableDemoState extends State<DataTableDemo> {
  // other fields!
  DessertDataSource _dessertsDataSource = DessertDataSource([]);
  bool isLoaded = false;
```

Then add the following function to `_DataTableDemoState`. The boolean ensures we only make the http call once.

```
Future<void> getData() async {
  final results = await fetchResults(http.Client);
  if (!isLoaded) {
      setState(() {
        _dessertsDataSource = DessertDataSource(results);
        isLoaded = true;
      });
  }
}
```

Finally call that function upon pressing a button or some other trigger or maybe just at the beginning of your build function.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getData();
    return MYWidget();
}
```

Then whenever the data is returned from the http call, the widget will automatically update with the new data.

Comment: Is there anyway to change the future to a list without using FutureBuilder. My class extends DataTableSource and I'd like to instantiate the list in that class because of the necessary sorting on the list by the implemented methods.

Comment: @user2387962  i edited it it describes a method where you don't need to use a FutureBuilder.

Comment: thanks but  `(await fetchResults(http.Client));` doesn't compile

Comment: @user2387962 ah that was probably because it was inside setState... I edited it again